# Error when trying to run behat tests. usr/bin/env Invalid argument

Tags: php, testing, error-handling, configuration, behat

I am trying to learn how to work with behat test. I am following this tutorial: https://www.mindyourownwebsite.com.au/installing-behat-3-mink-selenium-windows/

I managed to install everything that is required but when I get to the part where I have to run the behat tests:

```
/mypath/behat/bin/behat --config /projectPath/behat/behat.yml -p test:chrome 
/projectPath/behat/tests/
```

I got an error: /usr/bin/env **php** no such file or directory

I've made sure that I have php in my $PATH variable in git bash. Because nothing worked, I copied the php executable into /usr/bin/env:

```
cp /mypath/php/php.exe /usr/bin/env
```

Now when I try to run the behat test with the command mentioned above I get the error:

```
/usr/bin/env: Invalid argument
```

I really don't know what is the problem or how to fix this.

Thanks for any help!

Comment: `cp /mypath/php/php.exe /usr/bin/env` congratulations, you just broke the machine.

Comment: Why? And how can I fix this? Sorry I'm new to this.

Comment: `/usr/bin/env` is a program used to return the absolute path of a binary, and you just overwrote it with the php binary. I'm not familiar with how git bash works, but *before* doing this you should have checked that `/usr/bin/env php` returned something. If it didn't maybe you needed `/usr/bin/env php.exe` (again, I don't know as I'm not a git bash user). All of this, of course, assumes that `php` was *really* in your path. Finally, a word of advice: when you see something you don't know, first do some reasearch, then act.

Comment: About how to revert the mistake, I guess you could do worse than re-insall git-bash.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your issue might have been that you didn't add php to environment variables.

> Don't forget that after you add any env variable you need to restart any opened command line

1. You don't need MAMP
2. You need to install: php, composer, java, git
3. For php extract and add the path to php.exe to `Path` environment variable
4. Also for php you need to rename a php ini file to `php.ini` and enable the following extensions: curl, mbstring, openssl

**Behat**
1. You need a `composer.json` file that contains required packages
2. Put this in a project directory, open command line or git bash there and execute
 `composer install --prefer-dist`
3. Add your `behat.yml` config file in the same directory as composer file
4. Run `bin/behat --init` to create the basic structure

> For large project I recommend to use it with page objects, you can also find extension for html report with included screenshot.

Answer (score 0):

I'm a linux user, but I think that in windows does not work that way.

Firstly ensure you have a right version of php configured and working

```
php -v
```

Now test if behat is working:

```
php /mypath/behat/bin/behat --version
```

Now try to run your tests with:

```
php /mypath/behat/bin/behat --config /projectPath/behat/behat.yml -p test:chrome /projectPath/behat/tests/
```